What is a "type" in type theory?
Types are taken as atomic in type theories like homotopy type theory. But what is the best way to conceptualize what a type is? Is it appropriate to think of them as a property that defines a category?

Types are an interpretation of a representation. So for a binary expression it might be an integer, string, float or instructions depending on context. This interpretation is governed by certain rules that make up the type system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

Answers to this question as given by models of type theory. The standard set-theoretic model says "a type is a set". The "standard" model of homotopy type theory says "a type is an $\infty$-groupoid". Realisability models might give more down-to-earth answers.

I'd say something like: think of a type as being like a set (such as a set of possible values for a variable to take) - but freed of the preconception "set theory" people tend to have that everything mathematical is a set.  Instead, elements of a type don't necessarily need to be treated as sets or types in turn.  Also, type theories usually don't allow you to ask whether elements of two different types are equal -- so for example the statement $0 = (5, 6)$ "isn't even wrong", it doesn't even make sense to ask the question because the two sides have different types.

@CyclotomicField: As I've noted in the answer I've posted, type theory / type theories and type systems are not synonymous. In type theory, types don't 'need' an underlying encoding at all, and aren't merely an 'interpretation' of it. For example: we can define the 'type' of prime numbers, regardless of how (if at all) we might choose to encode that type on computing hardware.

@DanielSchepler: That's why i use the word 'collection' in my answer - I feel it reduces the chances of people slipping into thinking in set-theoretic terms.

(1/2) @DanielSchepler "I'd say something like: think of a type as being like a set" except that (as you point out) it isn't: a set-based interpretation is in fact rather problematic: "spaces have structure, sets don't"...

(2/2) @Alexis ...and, talking of "collections" does not make things better in that sense.


Types are taken as atomic in type theories like homotopy type theory.

The notion of type is primitive in type theory, not atomic.
That said, interpretations of type theory may have types as sets, types as spaces, types as propositions, see e.g. here (just the first result of a web search): INTRODUCTION TO TYPE THEORY - F. Shinko
Types as "spaces" in particular is homotopy type theory, which is in fact not type theory per se, it is an interpretation of types and, possibly, a meta-theory.

Essentially, a 'type', in both type theory and type systems, refers to a collection of items that share a property or properties. As others have noted, 'types' can be interpreted in various ways in various contexts.
As a couple of asides:

Type theory and type systems are not identical! While there's substantial overlap, and the two can inform each other, type theory is primarily a field of mathematics and logic, while type systems are primarily part of the field of computing.

There is a subtlety of language, where one can talk of 'type theory' as an overall field, and a type theory, as a specific collection of rules for creating and using types. Thus, it's possible to talk of e.g. 'dependent type theories' as a specific sub-field within the field of 'type theory'.



Thank you. The confusing part is a type looks a lot like a set!

Why was this downvoted? @Alexis gave a helpful answer.
